# How to convert datetime format on Azure Logs Query

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

I want to format the datetime on Azure Log this is the date time format

DATETIME = 01/Sep/2022:04:48:11 +0000

I tried to split and get 01/Sep/2022 but it wont convert

```
SampleLog_CL 
| extend raw = parse_json(RawData).log
| parse raw with DATETIME
| extend dt = split(DATETIME, ':')
| project DATE=format_datetime(todatetime(dt[0]), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

when I try to put the actual value 01/Sep/2022 it can convert

```
SampleLog_CL 
| extend raw = parse_json(RawData).log
| parse raw with DATETIME
| extend dt = split(DATETIME, ':')
| project DATE=format_datetime(todatetime("01/Sep/2022"), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

How can I convert it?

Comment: There's no reason whatsoever to use anything else but ISO date/timestamp formats, as well as UTC, in back-end systems. This should be fixed in the source, not in a query.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz is there is no way for this to be formatted?

Comment: A really ugly one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution
let SampleLog_CL = datatable(RawData:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({"log":"01/Sep/2022:04:48:11 +0000"})
];
// Solution starts here
let months = dynamic({"Jan":01, "Feb":"02", "Mar":"03", "Apr":"04", "May":"05", "Jun":"06", "Jul":"07", "Aug":"08", "Sep":"09", "Oct":"10", "Nov":"11", "Dec":"12"});
SampleLog_CL 
| extend raw = parse_json(RawData).log
| parse raw with d "/" M "/" y ":" h ":" m ":" s " " o
| extend Timestamp = todatetime(strcat(y, "-", months[M], "-", d, " ", h, ":", m, ":", s, o))
```

| RawData | raw | d | M | y | h | m | s | o | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"log":"01/Sep/2022:04:48:11 +0000"} | 01/Sep/2022:04:48:11 +0000 | 01 | Sep | 2022 | 04 | 48 | 11 | +0000 | 2022-09-01T04:48:11Z |